# Compare string object equals to element in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda, comparison

So im new to c++ and its wrecking my mind a little. So I need help.Im trying to search an `String object`in `vector<Objects>` and see if they equal. was searching and i decided to use c++11 lamba expressions it keeps giving me errors:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3867   'User::getEmail': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    EmailServerClientApp    c:\users\user\desktop\emailserverclientapp\emailserverclientapp\guinterface.cpp 110 

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion) EmailServerClientApp    c:\users\user\desktop\emailserverclientapp\emailserverclientapp\guinterface.cpp 110
```

I created an overload operator(Or at least to my knowledge of c++ I think I did). Can't see whats wrong with this.

This is my users class :

```
    private:
    string userName;
    string password;
    string email;

public:
    User();
    User(string name, string pass, string e);

    void setUserName(string name);
    void setPassword(string pass);
    void setEmail(string e);
    bool numberInString(const std::string& s);
    void print()const;

    User &operator=(User other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy assignment of Email\n";
        std::swap(userName, other.userName);
        std::swap(password, other.password);
        std::swap(email, other.email);
        return *this;
    }
    friend bool operator ==(const User &c1, const string &e);



    string getUserName()const;
    string getPassword()const;
    string getEmail()const;

    ~User();
};
```

The operator created to check if equals:

```
bool operator==(const User & c1, const string& e )
{
    return (c1.email == e);

}
```

And this method here I'm trying to find the actual email in the vector:

```
bool checkIfUserExists(vector<User> v,string email, string password) {/* using c++11 lamba expression to find an 
                                                                      element in vector matching my string object 
                                                                      */
    vector<User>::iterator it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&email](const User&c1) {return c1.getEmail == email; });

        if (it != v.end())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

what am I doing wrong. Please I need help with this. would be crying anytime soon. Thank you in advance

Comment: There is nothing wrong in checkIfUserExists except in lambda you forget call c1.getEmail().

Comment: oh my God. cant believe i didnt see that

Comment: Been Looking at that for a few hours now :(

Comment: Notice you could make use of your `operator==` that you defined, so simply: `it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), email)` !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{return c1.getEmail == email;}
```

`getEmail()` is a class method, not a class member. The correct syntax should be:

```
{return c1.getEmail() == email;}
```

Comment: Oh My God. going to jump off the roof now. hahah